# Как рекомендуется реализовать интерфейс с параметром и в чем будет разница?

Tags: java

Есть параметризованный интерфейс:

```
public interface Result<T extends Message> {
    T getMessage();
}
```

Мой вариант:

```
public class MyResult implements Result<MyMessage> {
    @Override
    public MyMessage  getMessage() {return null;}
}
```

1. Еще вроде как можно писать `MyResult<E extends MyMessage>`...Может еще есть какие варианты?
2. Есть какие рекомендации как писать и в чем разница?
3. Можно ли использовать метод ниже для создания MyResult?

   ```
   protected final <T extends Message> Result<T> createResult(Class<T> class) {}
   ```

Answer (score 1):

1. Разница в том что в случае

   class MyResult implements Result

`MyResult` будет иметь параметр, а случае

```
class MyResult implements Result<MyMessage>
```

получится не параметризованный класс.

2. Как писать зависит от того что вы хотите получить.
3. Можно. В случае не параметризованного класса единственный осмысленный аргумент для этого метода будет `Message.class`. Для параметризованной версии любой наследник `Message` подойдет.

Comment: в каком втором варианте? там интерфейс и его имплементация. 1 интерфейс - 1 вариант или нет?

Comment: В случае `MyResult<E extends MyMessage>`.

Comment: @talex, это очевидно. Хотелось бы услышать на что это в дальнейшем повлияет.

Comment: Не очень понятен вопрос. Вы не знаете что такое параметризованные классы? И чем они отличаются от не параметризованных?

Comment: @talex, более менее понимаю это. Но когда задавал вопрос - было не очевиден ваш ответ. Остается 3й вопрос. Спасибо.

Comment: @Alexey немного дополнил

Comment: @talex, "Можно - не работает. MyResult myResult = createResult(MyMessage.class); - Incompatible types.

Comment: @Alexey да, нужны явные преобразования типа.

Comment: @talex, какие? Так не работает - = (MyResult)createResult(MyMessage.class)

Comment: `(MyResult)(Object)createResult(MyMessage.class) `